# How to recognize paginator change event in lazy loading load() method

Tags: primefaces

I use primefaces datatable with lazy loading. Lazy loading method load is called after sort change, filter change and page change . I need to recognize event in load method (sort,filter or page).

```
load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
  //get event 
 //if event == page 
// do something  }
```

Comment: Why can't you use the ajax events? If you really can't, the answer by @Hoessein is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no explicit way. 
but you can do some implementations in order to find out, for example, you can have an attribute named lastTimeFirstValue, and each time the load is called, check it, if it is the same value, so it is not a page event, if it is different so it is a page event so it must be updated.